# Fees for Fermoposta (Poste Restante) in Italy

Tags: italy, mail

I'd like to get a parcel delivered to a post office in Italy using a poste restante service, so I can pick it up when I arrive there.

[Poste Italiane's website](https://www.poste.it/prodotti/fermoposta.html) seems to suggest (albeit through Google Translate) that there is a €3 fee per parcel, paid for by the sender. Is that correct? I would have expected it to be paid by the recipient but want to check as my sender is unlikely to be willing to pay for that fee and recharge it to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is that correct?

Yes, this is how it works

If you use stamps, you add €3 worth of stamps on top of the existing stamps and if you post using vignettes (more likely), you need to pay a vignette worth €3 more on top of the postage fees

Comment: Thanks - do you know what happens if the sender doesn’t pay the extra? Does the recipient have the option of paying or does it just get returned to the sender?

Comment: It's an optional service, if you don't pay for it in advance you won't get it, probably the envelope will be sent back to the sender. Remember that in the envelope you must write "FERMOPOSTA", the postal code and name of the postal office where the enveloper will sit, and the complete first and last name of the receiver (that must show a document for pick it up). The receiver has 30 days for pick it up, afterwards the envelope will be sent back to the sender.